# How do I keep a console window open after my python program terminates to see any errors produced?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3 on Win10 and running my code by opening a Command Prompt window and typing the file location. However, the window closes as soon as the program terminates, and before I can read any errors.
Edit: This happens whether or not the program has errors.
Thank you.

Comment: Run it as `python name_of_yourscript.py` to execute in the same console context.

Comment: Curious. I'm using Windows 10 too, and my command prompt stays open, whether or not the program terminated due to an exception, and whether or not I ran it with `python myscript.py` or just `myscript.py`.

Comment: @zwer When I do that, I recieve the error 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

I just saw your comment:

> When I do that, I recieve the error 'python' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file

It looks like you haven't specified the path to the python executable: you need to add the python executable path to your Window's PATH variable. You can see how to do that here: [Add Python to the PATH Environmental Variable (‘python’ is not recognized as an internal or external command)](https://www.pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/)

**Solution 2**:

You can use `input("enter to exit")` at the end of your python code to keep the program alive. It would exit once you press enter.

You could also surround your code in a `try` `except` statement and place thr `input()` in the `except` to prevent the program from exiting when there are errors, but like @Kevin mentioned in the comments, this would catch run time errors but not syntax errors.

**Solution 3**:

You can write errors or anything information you want to a file such as `log.txt` for example, and then read that log file once the code finishes running e.g. [how to write to a file in Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)

Comment: `input()` won't execute if the script is terminating earlier than that due to an exception. Doesn't seem like an effective way to see errors.

Comment: I agree, it is a solution to keep the window open only if there are no errors. I guess he could surround his code with a try-except and place `input()` in the except

Comment: That ought to work on runtime errors, sure, but it won't do much good against SyntaxErrors, which get raised before any `try` block could be entered.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I have several Python versions on my Windows system, so I don't want to add any Python directories to my path permanently.

Code for each version is in a separate folder (e.g. 'py37'), with a subfolder for each project e.g. 'myProject'.
In py37, there's a batch file called pyEnv.bat with this content:

```
@echo off
path=%path%;C:\Python37\;C:\Python37\Scripts\
cd.
cmd
```

In Windows explorer, I head over to the project folder I want to work in, click in the address bar and type `..\pyEnv`. That launches a DOS-box, in which I now can do `python myproject.py`. You can see `print()` output, errors, and so on.

You can up-arrow to try different modules, having typed them first.

Once you quit the DOS-box, your path is back to normal again.